# SPARQL output from two different subclasses

Tags: sparql, subclass

I would like to include the National Party and the EU Party Group of the Speaker in the output, as well as their committee membership **at the time of the respective speech**.

[Data Model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SoCkW.png)

[LinkedOpenData I am working with](https://linkedpolitics.project.cwi.nl/web/html/home.html)

When I just include the institution (here: ?party), it duplicates the speech for all the positions the speaker has ever had during his/her time in Parliament, rather than the current Committee Position. Furthermore, I have only managed to either get the National Party or the EU Party Group so far (see code below) but not both.

I would be glad for your help.

```
SELECT ?name ?gender ?partyname ?countryname ?date ?speechnr ?text 
WHERE {
  ?speech lpv:spokenText ?text.
  ?speech lpv:spokenAs ?function.
  ?function lpv:institution ?party. 
  ?party rdf:type lpv:NationalParty.
  ?party rdfs:label ?partyname.
  ?speech lpv:docno ?speechnr.
  ?speech dcterms:date ?date.
  ?speech lpv:speaker ?speaker.
  ?speaker lpv:name ?name.
  ?speaker lpv:gender ?gender.
  ?speaker lpv:countryOfRepresentation ?country. 
  ?country rdfs:label ?countryname.
  FILTER ( ?date >= "1999-07-20"^^xsd:date && ?date <= "2004-07-19"^^xsd:date ) 
  FILTER(langMatches(lang(?text), "en"))
  FILTER(CONTAINS(?text, 'domestic abuse') ||  CONTAINS(?text, 'domestic violence') ||  CONTAINS(?text, 'intimate partner violence') ||  CONTAINS(?text, 'rape') ||  CONTAINS(?text, 'sexual violence') ||  CONTAINS(?text, 'sexual assault') ||  CONTAINS(?text, 'gender base violence') ||  CONTAINS(?text, 'gender-based violence') ||  CONTAINS(?text, 'violence against women') ||  CONTAINS(?text, 'femicide') ||  CONTAINS(?text, 'witch-hunting death') ||  CONTAINS(?text, 'femicide-suicide') ||  CONTAINS(?text, 'excess female mortality')) 
  } ORDER BY ?date ?speechnr
```

Comment: your example query doesn't return any duplicate speech, or am I missing something? Can you give an example? I do not see in duplicate speech nr

Comment: if you want the position at time of the speech, you should use the `lpv:beginning` and `lpv:end` properties of the position and check if it includes the date of the speech

Comment: if you want to get `EUParty` or `NationalParty` why do you add a triple pattern like `?party rdf:type lpv:NationalParty.` at all? just omit it, there are no other types of party and you just want any of those or not?

Comment: I did word my question a little difficult. What I mean is, rather than having the same speech listed across six rows with one column for the different positions held at the time, I'd like to have one row and six columns with the different positions. The code I'm using now is similar to the above with a different beginning: 'SELECT ?name ?gender ?institution ?start ?end ?countryname ?date ?speechnr
WHERE {
  ?speech lpv:spokenText ?text.
  ?speech lpv:spokenAs ?function.
  ?function lpv:institution ?institution.
  ?function lpv:beginning ?start.
  ?function lpv:end ?end' and then ?date...

Comment: I guess I could do this in STATA later but the less I have to clean then, the better. Thank you for your time!!